# How can I use the Xamarin.Forms.Setter class in my own ContentView (custom control)?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating a `ContentView` custom control which I named `AutoAdaptingView`. Basically, it's a grid which can handle two `View` (FirstContent and SecondContent), and it will automatically put the two `View` in either two rows or two columns, depending on the orientation, screen height, etc.
Now, I want to create two attached `BindableProperty` named PortraitSetters and LandscapeSetters, which are `List<Setter>`, so that the consumer of this class can use XAML to declare variations of HorizontalOptions, RequestedHeight and any other relevant property using a list of `Setter`. That list will be scanned when the orientation changes, and it will use Reflection to set all the properties that need to be setted.
The problem is that if I use such list, it won't compile because it cannot convert from `string` to `BindableProperty`.

Here's my BindableProperty declaration:

```
        //
        public static readonly BindableProperty PortraitSettersProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
            "PortraitSetters",
            typeof(List<Setter>),
            typeof(AutoAdaptingView),
            null
        );

        public static List<Setter> GetPortraitSetters(BindableObject target)
        {
            return (List<Setter>)(target as View).GetValue(PortraitSettersProperty);
        }

        public static void SetPortraitSetters(BindableObject target, List<Setter> value)
        {
            (target as View).SetValue(PortraitSettersProperty, value);
        }

        //
        public static readonly BindableProperty LandscapeSettersProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
            "LandscapeSetters",
            typeof(List<Setter>),
            typeof(AutoAdaptingView),
            null
        );

        public static List<Setter> GetLandscapeSetters(BindableObject target)
        {
            return (List<Setter>)(target as View).GetValue(LandscapeSettersProperty);
        }

        public static void SetLandscapeSetters(BindableObject target, List<Setter> value)
        {
            (target as View).SetValue(LandscapeSettersProperty, value);
        }
```

Here's an example of how it would be used:

```
<ctrl:AutoAdaptingView>
    <ctrl:AutoAdaptingView.FirstContent>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                     Spacing="16">

            <ctrl:AutoAdaptingView.PortraitSetters>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Start"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="16, 100, 16, 16"/>
            </ctrl:AutoAdaptingView.PortraitSetters>

            <ctrl:AutoAdaptingView.LandscapeSetters>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="16"/>
            </ctrl:AutoAdaptingView.LandscapeSetters>

            <!-- actual content here -->
```

And here's the problem:

```
Cannot convert "HorizontalOptions" into Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty
```

Obviously I don't expect XAML to magically understand that the `Property` field refers to a `StackLayout` BindableProperty, but just in the same way that the `Style` class has a `TargetType` property that permits it to automatically convert the property name string to the actual `BindableProperty` object, there should be a way that permits me to implement the same.

A solution I thought about was to create my own Setter class that, instead of a `BindableProperty` object, it only takes a property name (since that is what I actually need in the implementation), but then wouldn't I need to create a converter in order to transform the values (i.e. `"16, 100, 16, 16"` to `new Margin(16, 100, 16, 16)`)?

The simplest solution would be to use an event instead, that the consumer will handle in the code behind, but this would cost the advantages of code-resource separation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your styles in App.xaml (Global styling)

```
<Style x:Key="portraitStyle" TargetType="custom:LabelEntry">
   <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="Start"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="16, 100, 16, 16"/>
</Style>
```

and, in your View Binding

```
Style="{Binding YourProperty , Converter={ StaticResource ConvertStyleKey }}"
```

With a converter for:

```
public class ConvertStyle : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        valueType = (YourModel)value
        if (valueType.YourProperty)
        {
            return Application.Current.Resources["portraitStyle"] as Style;
        }
        else
        {
            //other style
        }
    }
}
```